# How do I get searching through my command history working with tmux and zshell?

Tags: zsh, tmux

I use zshell and am trying out tmux.
In shell if I hit `control-R`, it fires off `bck-i-search` and I can begin typing to match commands previously entered. When in tmux, `control-R` appears to do nothing. I've tried searching around but can't seem to find any reason/solution for this.

Comment: It should work the same way under tmux. Bad config maybe?

Comment: Check your /etc/tmux.conf and ~/.tmux.conf . By default C-r is not bind to any command but could be your case. By default C-r works inside tmux shell (bash).

Answer (score 22):

Do you have an `export EDITOR=vi` somewhere in your `.zshrc` anywhere? I had a similar problem to this where <kbd>C-a</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd> and <kbd>C-r</kbd> worked fine until I started tmux. Turns out that the inner zsh was picking up on my EDITOR variable and switching keybindings to vi style. Setting up my `.zshrc` like this solved the problem:

```
# Use vi as the default editor
export EDITOR=vi

# But still use emacs-style zsh bindings
bindkey -e
```

Comment: Thanks yeah the really curious part about this is that tmux makes it happen

Comment: Thanks @Mat Schaffer, this helped me.

I investigated this issue a bit myself. It seems that the reason that the "outer" zsh (e.g. as used when a terminal window is started) uses the default Emacs keymap even when `EDITOR=vi[m]` is set in `.zshrc` is that the "outer" `zsh` is started with EDITOR unset. `tmux` starts a new `zsh` session, which picks up `EDITOR=vi[m]` and switches the keymap to Vi-style (as documented in `zshzle` man page). This also happens is you start an a new interactive "inner" zsh in a terminal without `tmux`.

`bindkeys -e` in `.zshrc` overrides this behaviour.

Answer (score 19):

Wound up adding `bindkey '^R' history-incremental-search-backward` to my .zshrc file and things are working.

Comment: I don't know what the interaction is between tmux and zsh that keeps this from working, but your fix worked for me. This has bothered me so much that I've actually been avoiding tmux. I can't thank you enough. THANK YOU!